# Create BOM Allocation In Sage200 by SDK

Tags: sage

I've done a lot of Sage200 integration work, but one area I've never mastered is creating BOM Allocations.

I can build them fine, but I can't seem to create a new one and add the finished items that I want to build it.

I'm assuming its all part of "AllocationCoordinatorFactory"?

Does anyone have a starting point to get finished products added?

Thanks!

I've tried to use BomAllocationFinishedItemFactory.Factory.CreateNew() but don't seem to get added to the allocation.